# How do I setup Drupal Console on Windows 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-console

How do I install/setup Drupal Console on Windows 7? In the video by the author, the environment used is Linux.

I tried to install it on Windows 7, but I wasn't able to use it to generate a module code.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. I have no idea what "Drupal 8 console" is. If you want run a server and drupal on windows 7, the easiest way might be to install "wampsever", add the drupal files to the www directory. That is how I have been doing it the past few years, until I started running a virtual machine.

Comment: Console project is available at https://www.drupal.org/project/console  project help in creating modules very fast. But I am not getting it worked on windows.

Comment: Oh, well maybe do what I do and run a virtual linux server on your machine. I use virtualBox

Comment: I have answered this drupal.stackexchange please visit [Install Drupal console on windows in 3 steps ](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221210/how-to-properly-set-up-drupal-console-on-windows-7/253997#253997)

Answer (score 3):

You can download the drupal console either using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) Bash

```
$curl https://drupalconsole.com/installer -L -o drupal
```

Or using windows command prompt

```
c:\>php -r "readfile('https://drupalconsole.com/installer');" > drupal
```

After downloading this file, place it beside php.exe file within your php  folder (not project folder), restart your terminal/cmd-prompt and type

```
$drupal
```

to get started.

Besides downloading Drupal Console .phar file, you can also install Drupal Console using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) on windows.

First Download and install composer in your system.

Then on your windows command prompt or git terminal

```
$composer global require drupal/console:@stable
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called drupal.bat

```
@php "%~dp0drupal.phar" %*
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the full list of steps I took:

- php -r "readfile('https://drupalconsole.com/installer');" > drupal.phar
- added installation location to the global PATH
- created a drupal.bat file in the same directory as drupal.phar. drupal.bat contains: `@php "%~dp0drupal.phar" %*`

Now you can call >drupal from any location.  I would upvote @Nate's answer, but this is a new account.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `Git bash` (or any terminal with `curl` capability)
- Run `curl https://drupalconsole.com/installer -L -o drupal.phar`
- Create file `drupal.bat` with content `@php "%~dp0drupal.phar" %*`
- Copy both files (`drupal.phar` and `drupal.bat`) into `C:\WINDOWS`
- Open new `Command prompt` window then try typing `drupal list`.

This steps assume:

- Your PHP is on `Path` environment variables and you can run `php --version`.
- You have Git for Windows installed.

Answer (score 1):

you can install `drupal console` using `composer`

open the command line on windows then go to :

```
cd /path/to/drupal8.dev
```

now you can install `drupal console` :

```
composer require drupal/console:~1.0 --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
```

after that you installed `drupal console` you can use it from drupal root directory where composer.json exist as follow:

```
vendor/bin/drupal <the_command>
```

you should replace `<the_command>` with one of the `drupal console` commands. you can see complete list of the commands here: [drupal console commands](https://drupalconsole.com/docs/en/commands/)

Answer (score 0):

- Find a php.exe
- Add this path to the environnement variable path
- from terminal run

  ```
  php -r "readfile('https://drupalconsole.com/installer');" > drupal.phar
  ```
- i then use php-storm IDE :
- file/settings/command line
- add tool based on symfony console
- fill php path and drupal.phar path
- console is now set
- tools/run command

  ```
  drupal list
  ```

Answer (score 0):

if you have php and composer all setup
make sure you're in your drupal root folder..open powershell (anyother cli) and do '

```
composer require drupal/console
```

'after this add.
     `'C:\<path to your drupalwebsite root folder>\vendor\bin'`
 to your paths Environment variables

and you have composer installed: Remember to install and add composer to path variables for every local drupal installation.